# Favicon content-type incorrect in Express

Tags: node.js, express, favicon

In Express, when I include a set of favicons with the `type` set, according to the Response Headers, the images are coming in with a `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`

For example,

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/public/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

In the Network tab in Chrome:

[image]

In my express application, I'm doing the following:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

**How do I ensure the Content-Type is correct for these images in Express?**

Answer (score 0):

Your root path is already `./public`, so specifying it also in your HTML is incorrect. In your HTML for your favicon, it would just be `/images/favicon-16x16.png`.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks alot. Is there a way to expose a local variable to do something like: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{APP_FAVICON}}" sizes="16x16">`?

Comment: Yes, you need to pick a template engine. There are lots of those to choose from that are compatible with Express. You might look at an engine like [`ejs`](https://github.com/mde/ejs) if you want to re-use existing HTML markup though.